# strcat function still works when destination string array is too small

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have to recreate a bunch of string functions for homework.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *strcat1(char *s1, const char *s2);
int main(void)
{
    char string[4] = "asd";
    char string1[4] = "asd";
    char string2[] = "teststring";
    printf("%s\n", strcat(string, string2));
    printf("%s\n", strcat1(string1, string2));
}
char *strcat1(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t a=0;
    for(a;s1[a]!='\0';a++)
    {
    }
    size_t b=0;
    for(b;s2[b]!='\0';a++,b++)
    {
        s1[a]=s2[b];
    }
    s1[a]=s2[b];
    return s1;
}
```

the output is:

```
asdteststring
asdteststring
```

`string` and `string1` can hold 3 characters + \0, so   after `a` in `s1[a]` passes 3 shouldn't it fail? Why does it still work? I came across the same thing when recreating strcpy.

Comment: The program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code exhibits [undefined behaviour (UB)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) because, as you say, your target buffer is not sufficiently large to hold the string. Therefore you do not satisfy the requirements of the library function you use. UB doesn't mean that the program necessarily crashes, it means that it *may* crash.

The reason this doesn't happen in this case is because the buffer you allocate sits on the memory part that is organised as a stack. Hence, the memory past the end of the buffer exists. It just doesn't belong to the variable you think it belongs to.

---

In fact, if you compile your program with `-fsanitize=address` you see that `strcat` actually causes a buffer overrun:

```
=================================================================
==16978==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffd3f946594 at pc 0x7ff2aec575f3 bp 0x7ffd3f946560 sp 0x7ffd3f945d10
WRITE of size 11 at 0x7ffd3f946594 thread T0
    #0 0x7ff2aec575f2 in __interceptor_strcat (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0xa95f2)
    #1 0x5638a1480330 in main (/tmp/_/a.out+0x1330)
    #2 0x7ff2aea11e0a in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308
    #3 0x5638a14800f9 in _start (/tmp/_/a.out+0x10f9)

Address 0x7ffd3f946594 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 36 in frame
    #0 0x5638a14801c4 in main (/tmp/_/a.out+0x11c4)

  This frame has 3 object(s):
    [32, 36) 'string' (line 6) <== Memory access at offset 36 overflows this variable
    [48, 52) 'string1' (line 7)
    [64, 75) 'string2' (line 8)
```

So, following this diagnostic, if I print `string`, I get this:

> eststring
>   Segmentation fault

Although `string` should still be `asd`.